# Scroll to a Specified Row in an Extended Data-Table Using AJAX4JSF and/or JSF/RichFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I would like to scroll automatically to a given row in a JSF/RichFaces Extended Data-table (rich:extendedDataTable).  Ideally, I would like to use two extended data-tables with vertical scrollbars on both.

1. When I select a row in a first table the corresponding row gets selected in the second table (do this from the managed bean, by playing with the selection attribute of my table).
2. The second table then scrolls automatically so that the selected row becomes visible, even if hidden.
3. The solution should not involve the rich:datascroller, but instead use the out-of-box JSF/RichFaces vertical scrolling.

Thanks for helping!

Matthieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So well I finally developed my own kind of scrollable datatable, playing dynamically with the "first" and "rows" tags of both the datatable and collapsible subtable.

Relevant values are dynamically computed by the managed bean.

Comment: If you've developed it, please share!  Others may be attempting to do the same thing.